# Intel Pintools: How to count the number of static and basic blocks?

Tags: pintool, intel

I am using [Intel Pintool BBLs](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/98484/Pin/html/group__BBL.html) to count the total number of static and dynamic basic blocks.

The below is the distinguish between static vs dynamic basic blocks (bbls):

> A dynamic basic block is defined as a sequential run of instructions
> that starts with an instruction that is a target of a **taken** branch and
> ends with the first taken branch in sequence. Thus, one dynamic basic
> block may contain one or more static basic blocks that are defined as
> follows: a sequential run of instructions that starts with an
> instruction that is a target of a taken branch and ends with the first
> **branch** in sequence

[Intel Pintool User Manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/98484/Pin/html/index.html)  defines their basic block (BBLs) as:

> Pin breaks the trace into basic blocks, BBLs. A BBL is a single
> entrance, single exit sequence of instructions. Branches to the middle
> of a bbl begin a new trace and hence a new BBL

I am not clear if Pintool BBLs is static or dynamic bbls?

Please advice!